# How to close current JFrame instead of both?

Tags: java, jframe

Hi im having trouble figuring out why it closes both the main and current JFrame at the same time. the part i highlighted in bold is where im having trouble. when im in the main frame and click the events button and then exit it also exit main frame

```
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            if (e.getSource() == m_btnAddRemoveFriend) {
                openAddRemoveGUI();
                //If the log out button is pressed, open Login
            } else if (e.getSource() == m_btnLogOut) {
                logOut();
            } else if (e.getSource() == m_contactsList) {
                openCommHist();
            } else if (e.getSource() == m_groupConversationsList) {
                openMultiRepHist();
            } else if (e.getSource() == m_btnSendMessage) {
                openSendMessageGUI();
            } else if (e.getSource() == m_friendRequestsList) {
                openFriendRequestGUI();
            } else if (e.getSource() == m_btnCollaborativeDrawingEnvironment) {
               openDrawingEnvGUI();
            } else if (e.getSource() == m_btnAccountSettings) {
                 openAccountSettingsGUI();
            **} else if (e.getSource() == m_btnProductTable) {
            new ProductTable().setVisible(true);
                Skypertawe.saveApplicationState();
            }**
```

Comment: Where have you assigned the close behaviour of the Frame(s)?

Comment: By the way - worth a read. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice?rq=1

Comment: “when im in the main frame and click the events button …” What events button?  I see no events button in your code.